# Error running gradle command but not using AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that uses com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1 which I can run and unit test using AndroidStudio but when I try to run the project using the command line I get the following errors:

```
$ sh gradlew :myproject:clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myproject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproject:_normalDebugAndroidTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.0.2/support-annotations-25.0.2.pom
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.0.2/support-annotations-25.0.2.jar
         file:/Users/Joan/Development/myproject/git/android-tag/src/myproject/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.0.2/support-annotations-25.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :myproject
   > Could not find com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.jar
         file:/Users/Joan/Development/myproject/git/android-tag/src/myproject/sdk-manager/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :myproject
   > Could not find com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/test/rules/1.0.1/rules-1.0.1.pom
         file:/Users/Joan/SDKs/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/test/rules/1.0.1/rules-1.0.1.jar
         file:/Users/Joan/Development/myproject/git/android-tag/src/myproject/sdk-manager/com/android/support/test/rules/1.0.1/rules-1.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :myproject

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.437 secs
```

I'm using gradle 2.3.3 and for now I can not update to the latest one because of some backward compatibility issues.

how can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you missed the `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in your `build.gradle`. That is why it only searched the maven cache.

Ensure you have something like this in your project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Also, you can run the Gradle task as `./gradlew :myproject:clean` instead of `sh gradlew :myproject:clean`.